# fast way to copy formatting in excel

Tags: vba, copy, format, rtf

I have two bits of code. First a standard copy paste from cell A to cell B

```
Sheets(sheet_).Cells(x, 1).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Output").Cells(startrow, 2)
```

I can do almost the same using

```
Sheets("Output").Cells(startrow, 2) = Sheets(sheet_).Cells(x, 1)
```

Now this second method is much faster, avoiding copying to clipboard and pasting again. However it does not copy across the formatting as the first method does. The Second version is almost instant to copy 500 lines, while the first method adds about 5 seconds to the time. And the final version could be upwards of 5000 cells.

So my question can the second line be altered to included the cell formatting (mainly font colour) while still staying fast.

Ideally I would like to be able to copy the cell values to a array/list along with the font formatting so I can do further sorting and operations on them before I "paste" them back on to the worksheet..

So my ideal solution would be some thing like

```
for x = 0 to 5000
array(x) = Sheets(sheet_).Cells(x, 1) 'including formatting
next

for x = 0 to 5000
Sheets("Output").Cells(x, 1)
next
```

is it possible to use RTF strings in VBA or is that only possible in vb.net, etc.

***Answer****

Just to see how my origianl method and new method compar, here are the results or before and after

New code = 65msec

```
Sheets("Output").Cells(startrow, 2) = Sheets(sheet_).Cells(x, 1)
Sheets("Output").Range("B" & startrow).Font.ColorIndex = Sheets(sheet_).Range("A" & x).Font.ColorIndex 'copy font colour as well
```

Old code = 1296msec

```
'Sheets("Output").Cells(startrow, 2).Value = Sheets(sheet_).Cells(x, 1)
'Sheets(sheet_).Cells(x, 1).Copy
'Sheets("Output").Cells(startrow, 2).PasteSpecial (xlPasteFormats)
'Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For me, you can't. But if that suits your needs, you could have speed *and* formatting by copying the whole range at once, instead of looping:

```
range("B2:B5002").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Output").Cells(startrow, 2)
```

And, by the way, you can build a custom range string, like `Range("B2:B4, B6, B11:B18")`

---

**edit**: if your source is "sparse", can't you just format the destination at once when the copy is finished ?

Comment: Although I could calculate the range the cells I am copying from are not in a range. The code searches multiply sheets for a given criteria, if it finds a row that meets the criteria it copies a specific cell from that row to the output sheet. So while the out put row will incress each loop by 1. the value for sheets_ and the input row will be random, and as said there will be thousands. And yes a database would possible be the way to go, but not possible at the moment.

Comment: I will try that seems a good possibility. the other alternative is to copy them in to an array and check font colour and copy in to second element. Having them in an array would allow me to carry out some other stuff.

Comment: PS how about if you need to build a range across mutiply sheets?

Comment: And what about formatting the destination at once, when the copy is over ?

Comment: depending on the source the formatting may be different, so one copied cell may have a blue font the next red and another green. I think the range idea is good. seeing how that goes

Comment: I found another way to do this using the "Font.ColorIndex" property of range. so .range("A2").Font.ColorIndex = .range("A6").Font.ColorIndex. give a very fast result. It also means I can if i want copy both he text and font colour to varibles such as an arrey/list if I want.

Comment: No thank you, I am always impressed by the level of help I receive here. Thank you

Answer (score 17):

You could have simply used `Range("x1").value(11)` 
something like below:

```
Sheets("Output").Range("$A$1:$A$500").value(11) =  Sheets(sheet_).Range("$A$1:$A$500").value(11)
```

range has default property "Value" plus value can have 3 optional orguments 10,11,12.
11 is what you need to tansfer both value and formats. It doesn't use clipboard so it is faster.- Durgesh

Comment: @durgesch This is really useful, but is there also a numeric value which will transpose my data as well as maintain the format?

Comment: @DaSpotz wrap the second half of the statement in `Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose()`.  Bear in mind you will also need to transpose the address of your target range.

Answer (score 3):

Remember that when you write:

```
MyArray = Range("A1:A5000")
```

you are really writing

```
MyArray = Range("A1:A5000").Value
```

You can also use names:

```
MyArray = Names("MyWSTable").RefersToRange.Value
```

But Value is not the only property of Range.  I have used:

```
MyArray = Range("A1:A5000").NumberFormat
```

I doubt

```
MyArray = Range("A1:A5000").Font
```

would work but I would expect

```
MyArray = Range("A1:A5000").Font.Bold
```

to work.

I do not know what formats you want to copy so you will have to try.

However, I must add that when you copy and paste a large range, it is not as much slower than doing it via an array as we all thought.

**Post Edit information**

Having posted the above I tried by own advice.  My experiments with copying Font.Color and Font.Bold to an array have failed.

Of the following statements, the second would fail with a type mismatch:

```
  ValueArray = .Range("A1:T5000").Value
  ColourArray = .Range("A1:T5000").Font.Color
```

ValueArray must be of type variant.  I tried both variant and long for ColourArray without success.

I filled ColourArray with values and tried the following statement:

```
  .Range("A1:T5000").Font.Color = ColourArray
```

The entire range would be coloured according to the first element of ColourArray and then Excel looped consuming about 45% of the processor time until I terminated it with the Task Manager.

There is a time penalty associated with switching between worksheets but recent questions about macro duration have caused everyone to review our belief that working via arrays was substantially quicker.

I constructed an experiment that broadly reflects your requirement.  I filled worksheet Time1 with 5000 rows of 20 cells which were selectively formatted as: bold, italic, underline, subscript, bordered, red, green, blue, brown, yellow and gray-80%.

With version 1, I copied every 7th cells from worksheet "Time1" to worksheet "Time2" using copy.

With version 2, I copied every 7th cells from worksheet "Time1" to worksheet "Time2" by copying the value and the colour via an array.

With version 3, I copied every 7th cells from worksheet "Time1" to worksheet "Time2" by copying the formula and the colour via an array.

Version 1 took an average of 12.43 seconds, version 2 took an average of 1.47 seconds while version 3 took an average of 1.83 seconds.  Version 1 copied formulae and all formatting, version 2 copied values and colour while version 3 copied formulae and colour.  With versions 1 and 2 you could add bold and italic, say, and still have some time in hand.  However, I am not sure it would be worth the bother given that copying 21,300 values only takes 12 seconds.

** Code for Version 1**

I do not think this code includes anything that needs an explanation.  Respond with a comment if I am wrong and I will fix.

```
Sub SelectionCopyAndPaste()

  Dim ColDestCrnt As Integer
  Dim ColSrcCrnt As Integer
  Dim NumSelect As Long
  Dim RowDestCrnt As Integer
  Dim RowSrcCrnt As Integer
  Dim StartTime As Single

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
  NumSelect = 1
  ColDestCrnt = 1
  RowDestCrnt = 1
  With Sheets("Time2")
    .Range("A1:T715").EntireRow.Delete
  End With
  StartTime = Timer
  Do While True
    ColSrcCrnt = (NumSelect Mod 20) + 1
    RowSrcCrnt = (NumSelect - ColSrcCrnt) / 20 + 1
    If RowSrcCrnt > 5000 Then
      Exit Do
    End If
    Sheets("Time1").Cells(RowSrcCrnt, ColSrcCrnt).Copy _
                 Destination:=Sheets("Time2").Cells(RowDestCrnt, ColDestCrnt)
    If ColDestCrnt = 20 Then
      ColDestCrnt = 1
      RowDestCrnt = RowDestCrnt + 1
    Else
     ColDestCrnt = ColDestCrnt + 1
    End If
    NumSelect = NumSelect + 7
  Loop
  Debug.Print Timer - StartTime
  ' Average 12.43 secs
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

** Code for Versions 2 and 3**

The User type definition must be placed before any subroutine in the module.  The code works through the source worksheet copying values or formulae and colours to the next element of the array.  Once selection has been completed, it copies the collected information to the destination worksheet.  This avoids switching between worksheets more than is essential.

```
Type ValueDtl
  Value As String
  Colour As Long
End Type

Sub SelectionViaArray()

  Dim ColDestCrnt As Integer
  Dim ColSrcCrnt As Integer
  Dim InxVLCrnt As Integer
  Dim InxVLCrntMax As Integer
  Dim NumSelect As Long
  Dim RowDestCrnt As Integer
  Dim RowSrcCrnt As Integer
  Dim StartTime As Single
  Dim ValueList() As ValueDtl

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

  ' I have sized the array to more than I expect to require because ReDim
  ' Preserve is expensive.  However, I will resize if I fill the array.
  ' For my experiment I know exactly how many elements I need but that
  ' might not be true for you.
  ReDim ValueList(1 To 25000)

  NumSelect = 1
  ColDestCrnt = 1
  RowDestCrnt = 1
  InxVLCrntMax = 0      ' Last used element in ValueList.
  With Sheets("Time2")
    .Range("A1:T715").EntireRow.Delete
  End With
  StartTime = Timer
  With Sheets("Time1")
    Do While True
      ColSrcCrnt = (NumSelect Mod 20) + 1
      RowSrcCrnt = (NumSelect - ColSrcCrnt) / 20 + 1
      If RowSrcCrnt > 5000 Then
        Exit Do
      End If
      InxVLCrntMax = InxVLCrntMax + 1
      If InxVLCrntMax > UBound(ValueList) Then
        ' Resize array if it has been filled 
        ReDim Preserve ValueList(1 To UBound(ValueList) + 1000)
      End If
      With .Cells(RowSrcCrnt, ColSrcCrnt)
        ValueList(InxVLCrntMax).Value = .Value              ' Version 2
        ValueList(InxVLCrntMax).Value = .Formula            ' Version 3
        ValueList(InxVLCrntMax).Colour = .Font.Color
      End With
      NumSelect = NumSelect + 7
    Loop
  End With
  With Sheets("Time2")
    For InxVLCrnt = 1 To InxVLCrntMax
      With .Cells(RowDestCrnt, ColDestCrnt)
        .Value = ValueList(InxVLCrnt).Value                 ' Version 2
        .Formula = ValueList(InxVLCrnt).Value               ' Version 3
        .Font.Color = ValueList(InxVLCrnt).Colour
      End With
      If ColDestCrnt = 20 Then
        ColDestCrnt = 1
        RowDestCrnt = RowDestCrnt + 1
      Else
       ColDestCrnt = ColDestCrnt + 1
      End If
    Next
  End With
  Debug.Print Timer - StartTime
  ' Version 2 average 1.47 secs
  ' Version 3 average 1.83 secs
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the NumberFormat property after the Value property:
In this example the Ranges are defined using variables called ColLetter and SheetRow and this comes from a for-next loop using the integer i, but they might be ordinary defined ranges of course.

TransferSheet.Range(ColLetter & SheetRow).Value = Range(ColLetter & i).Value
TransferSheet.Range(ColLetter & SheetRow).NumberFormat = Range(ColLetter & i).NumberFormat

Answer (score -2):

Does:

```
Set Sheets("Output").Range("$A$1:$A$500") =  Sheets(sheet_).Range("$A$1:$A$500")
```

...work? (I don't have Excel in front of me, so can't test.)

Comment: without even trying, that won't do the trick, since the default property of `Range` is `.Value`

Comment: Wouldn't it copy/reference the whole `Range` object, rather than just its default property?

Comment: This causes a run time error.  You can't use `Set` on ranges like that