# vba copy cell formatting without .Copy and .Paste

Tags: performance, excel, vba

Main goal for me is to completely avoid clipboard for any kind of copy and paste operation in VBA.

I am able to achieve this for copying values and formulas in the below manner.

- `Range("B1:B5").Value = Range("A1:A5").Value` -> for copying values
- `Range("B1:B5").Formula = Range("A1:A5").Formula` -> for copying formulas

Now the hard part is to copy cell/range formats (includes conditional formatting) as same as source range. Even this I am able to at the level cells (not from the level of ranges), but this is not the ideal case and runtime is too bad.

for e.g: `Cells(x,y).Font.Bold = Cells(u,v).Font.Bold`

Even after disabling calculation mode to manual and display alerts to false the runtime is too bad.

Can anyone suggest the best possible way to copy formats without clipboard and with better runtime.

Comment: possible duplicate of [fast way to copy formatting in excel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8617162/fast-way-to-copy-formatting-in-excel)

Comment: how about creating a secondary sub with a few custom parameters i.e. font_name, font_type, font_special_something and cell/range. then formatting inside that sub.

Comment: @Siddharth: Yes I referred to the link you suggested but that almost looks like looping through each cell and getting properties. This increases runtime because I have to take care of cell borders and various other things as well.

Comment: @glh: yes screen updation is disabled.

Comment: Easy way would be to do as suggested by @iDevlop in that link. Else you will have to create an array and store each and every property ex: borders, fonts, cell background, data validaton, conditional formatting... etc etc (which all can be messy)

Comment: Can you share a sample set of what you've already got along with any hanging points this method gives, e.g. it takes the time copying conditional formatting?

Comment: Also, I notice you've stated the `Cells()` property, is this intentional? As there will be instances where a `range` type copy will perform better, e.g. when updating font properties this can perform better if the range is changed.