# VBA paste range

Tags: excel, vba, range, paste

I would like to copy a range and paste it into another spreadsheet. The following code below gets the copies, but does not paste:

```
Sub Normalize()

    Dim Ticker As Range
    Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
    Set Ticker = Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(65, 1))
    Ticker.Copy
    
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    Cells(1, 1).Activate
    Ticker.PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
    
End Sub
```

How can I paste the copies into another sheet?

Comment: `Ticker.PasteSpecial` is pasting back to the same range you copied.

Comment: Thank you! but how do I copy and paste range to different worksheet?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

To literally fix your example you would use this:

```
Sub Normalize()


    Dim Ticker As Range
    Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
    Set Ticker = Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(65, 1))
    Ticker.Copy

    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll



End Sub
```

To Make slight improvments on it would be to get rid of the Select and Activates:

```
Sub Normalize()
    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(65, 1)).Copy Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, 1)
    End With
End Sub
```

but using the clipboard takes time and resources so the best way would be to avoid a copy and paste and just set the values equal to what you want.

```
Sub Normalize()
Dim CopyFrom As Range

Set CopyFrom = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2", [A65])
Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").Resize(CopyFrom.Rows.Count).Value = CopyFrom.Value

End Sub
```

To define the `CopyFrom` you can use anything you want to define the range, You could use `Range("A2:A65")`, `Range("A2",[A65])`, `Range("A2", "A65")` all would be valid entries. also if the A2:A65 Will never change the code could be further simplified to:

```
Sub Normalize()

Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:A65").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A66").Value

End Sub
```

I added the Copy from range, and the `Resize` property to make it slightly more dynamic in case you had other ranges you wanted to use in the future.

Comment: This will only get you the values and not the formats... I guess and I could be wrong but the user want to paste the formats as well? `icker.PasteSpecial xlPasteAll`

Comment: @user1700890 No errors? Is it because you want the formatting like Sid says?

Comment: No, I do not care about format, the last of part of code does not procude neither errors nor results. If I am Sheet2, it will generate error: 1004 Application-defined or object-defined error. and will highlight the line Set CopyFrom = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2", [A65])

Comment: @user1700890 : I tested the 2nd piece of code above by :@user2140261 and it works for me :)

Comment: Siddharth Rout: What about 3rd piece, did it work for you as well?

Comment: @user1700890 : Yes, with a slight modification. If you are in Sheet2 then try this... `Set CopyFrom = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2", "A65")` and then add `.Value` after `CopyFrom` so the line becomes  `Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").Resize(CopyFrom.Rows.Count).Value = CopyFrom.Value`

Comment: @user1700890 Sid is correct I forgot to set the value to the value. Updated the code.

Comment: You can include formatting by changing .Value to .Value(11), as explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27561793/5790580)

Answer (score 1):

I would try

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
Set Ticker = Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(65, 1))
Ticker.Copy

Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").Offset(0,0).Cells.Select
Worksheets("Sheet2").paste
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what I came up to when trying to copy-paste excel ranges with it's sizes and cell groups. It might be a little too specific for my problem but...:

'**
'Copies a table from one place to another
'TargetRange: where to put the new LayoutTable
'typee: If it is an Instalation Layout table(1) or Package Layout table(2)
'**

```
Sub CopyLayout(TargetRange As Range, typee As Integer)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Dim ncolumn As Integer
        Dim nrow As Integer

        SheetLayout.Activate
    If (typee = 1) Then 'is installation
        Range("installationlayout").Copy Destination:=TargetRange '@SHEET2 TEM DE PASSAR A SER A SHEET DO PROJECT PLAN!@@@@@
    ElseIf (typee = 2) Then 'is package
        Range("PackageLayout").Copy Destination:=TargetRange '@SHEET2 TEM DE PASSAR A SER A SHEET DO PROJECT PLAN!@@@@@
    End If

    Sheet2.Select 'SHEET2 TEM DE PASSAR A SER A SHEET DO PROJECT PLAN!@@@@@

    If typee = 1 Then
       nrow = SheetLayout.Range("installationlayout").Rows.Count
       ncolumn = SheetLayout.Range("installationlayout").Columns.Count

       Call RowHeightCorrector(SheetLayout.Range("installationlayout"), TargetRange.CurrentRegion, typee, nrow, ncolumn)
    ElseIf typee = 2 Then
       nrow = SheetLayout.Range("PackageLayout").Rows.Count
       ncolumn = SheetLayout.Range("PackageLayout").Columns.Count
       Call RowHeightCorrector(SheetLayout.Range("PackageLayout"), TargetRange.CurrentRegion, typee, nrow, ncolumn)
    End If
    Range("A1").Select 'Deselect the created table

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

'**
'Receives the Pasted Table Range and rearranjes it's properties
'accordingly to the original CopiedTable
'typee: If it is an Instalation Layout table(1) or Package Layout table(2)
'**

```
Function RowHeightCorrector(CopiedTable As Range, PastedTable As Range, typee As Integer, RowCount As Integer, ColumnCount As Integer)
    Dim R As Long, C As Long

    For R = 1 To RowCount
        PastedTable.Rows(R).RowHeight = CopiedTable.CurrentRegion.Rows(R).RowHeight
        If R >= 2 And R < RowCount Then
            PastedTable.Rows(R).Group 'Main group of the table
        End If
        If R = 2 Then
            PastedTable.Rows(R).Group 'both type of tables have a grouped section at relative position "2" of Rows
        ElseIf (R = 4 And typee = 1) Then
            PastedTable.Rows(R).Group 'If it is an installation materials table, it has two grouped sections...
        End If
    Next R

    For C = 1 To ColumnCount
        PastedTable.Columns(C).ColumnWidth = CopiedTable.CurrentRegion.Columns(C).ColumnWidth
    Next C
End Function



Sub test ()
    Call CopyLayout(Sheet2.Range("A18"), 2)
end sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like below to paste values in other ranges. (faster than copying and pasting values)

```
ThisWorkbook.WorkSheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:A2").Value = Sheets`("Sheet1").Range("A1:A2").Value
```