# Paste cells to another worksheet in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, cell, spreadsheet, copy-paste

I want to paste cells across worksheets in VBA. In the code below, I first select the range of cells, and then paste to another worksheet. But it runs error '9": Subscript out of range. I think the problem is in the last line for copy & paste. Here's my code:

```
Sub MatchFRB()
' find last row and column 
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastColumn As Long
Dim StartCell As Range
Set StartCell = Range("A1")
LastRow = Sheet22.Cells(Sheet22.Rows.Count, StartCell.Column).End(xlUp).Row
LastColumn = Sheet22.Cells(StartCell.Row, Sheet22.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

' Select cells until meets Threshold=5000000000
Dim i As Integer
Dim Bal As Double
Threshold = 0

For i = 2 To LastRow
Bal = Threshold + Range("AV" & i)
If Threshold > 5000000000# Then  
    Exit For
End If
    Next i 

' copy cells from Sheet22 and paste to Sheet21
Sheet22.Range(StartCell, Sheet22.Cells(i, LastColumn)).Copy Worksheets("Sheet21").Range(StartCell, Sheet21.Cells(i, LastColumn))

End Sub
```

Many thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VBA paste range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18968856/vba-paste-range)

Comment: Just a comment, it's a little confusing when you switch conventions for the worksheet.  `Sheet22.Range()` vs `Worksheets("Sheet21")`.  I'd pick one way and stick with that.  That being said, which line throws the error? (Click "Debug" when the error pops up).  Also, are the origin and destination ranges the same size?

Comment: `Set StartCell = Range("A1")` I'd fully qualify this line then try again - `Set StartCell = Sheet22.Range("A1")`

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow! This subject has been thoroughly discussed across several other posts on this website. Make sure you are setting the Range object on your destination sheet appropriately. Also, the step-by-step debugger on VBA can help you find the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to properly call to your sheet. VBA doesn't accept just the name of the sheet as an object. You have to reference to the sheet with `Worksheets("Sheet22")`, another option would be to set an object to be this:

```
Dim ws as object
set ws = Thisworkbook.Worksheets("Sheet22")
```

This way VBA knows you want Sheet22 from the book that the macro is in; otherwise you could specify the workbook with `Workbooks("YourWorkBookName").WorkSheets("SheetName")`.

From there you could use `ws.Range` as you were doing with `Sheet22`. Similarly, `StartCell` may be a range, but it only acts with the active sheet, so it wouldn't be a bad idea to reference it to a certain sheet and/or book as well. But in this case, I've left it out because it's always `A1` and that's simple enough to enter.

Later in your code when you're trying to calculate the balance, you also have to use `.Value` after you call your range so that you actually access the number stored in the cell. But if you're threshold is what you're checking you should be adding the `threshold` back to itself. However, I've chosen to just use `Bal` in this case because it made more sense to me.

```
Sub MatchFRB()
' find last row and column 
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastColumn As Long
Dim ws as object
Dim i As Integer
Dim Bal As Double

set ws = Thisworkbook.Worksheets("Sheet22")

LastRow = ws.Cells.Find("*", searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row
LastColumn = ws.Cells.Find("*", searchorder:=xlByColumns, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Column

' Select cells until meets Threshold=5000000000

Bal = 0

For i = 2 To LastRow
    Bal = Bal + ws.Range("AV" & i).Value
    If Bal >= 5000000000 Then  
        Exit For
    End If
Next i 

' copy cells from Sheet22 and paste to Sheet21
ws.Range("A1:" & Cells(i, LastColumn).Address).Copy Worksheets("Sheet21").Range("A1:", Cells(i, LastColumn).address)

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I tried the code, but it shows error at set ws = Thisworkbook.Worksheets("Sheet22")

Comment: @doututu It's likely because I forgot to Dim it at the top. I've added the line, let me know if that fixed it

Comment: Actually you did dim it and now it's dimmed twice. I just changed the last line of my original code to " Sheet22.Range(StartCell, Sheet22.Cells(i, LastColumn)).Copy Sheet21.Range("A1") ", and it works. Wondering here VBA calls sheet22 and sheet21 as object?

Comment: Oh, oops. I'm not too sure, I've never called a sheet like that myself.