# VBA Range.Copy transpose paste 1004 Error

Tags: excel, vba

I wrote this code, but it only works when sheet1 is active. If sheet2 is active and I run the code, there is 1004 error. I don't know why. Thank you in advance!

```
Public Sub trans()

    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(3, 2)).Copy
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").PasteSpecial Transpose:=True

End Sub
```

Comment: You need to qualify `Cells(1,1)...` with the worksheet too.

Comment: Hi K.Davis! Thank you!!!! I thought worksheet.("sheet1") is used to active sheet1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Range(“address”) notation, to make Worksheets("Sheet1") reference suffice:

```
Public Sub trans()

    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:B2").Copy
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").PasteSpecial Transpose:=True

End Sub
```

Or reference Worksheets("Sheet1") in a With...End With block to have Cells() reference it:

```
Public Sub trans()

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        .Range(.Cells(1,1), .Cells(3,2)).Copy
    End With  
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").PasteSpecial Transpose:=True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Before you can select a range from a different worksheet, that worksheet needs to be active. E.g. something like this:

```
Public Sub trans()
  Range(Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1), Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(3, 2)).Copy
  Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").PasteSpecial Transpose:=True
End Sub
```

Comment: _"Not entirely sure why..."_ would be because you are referencing the `ActiveSheet` when you don't explicitly qualify your ranges with the target sheet.

Comment: Yes, correct. Added that

Comment: Hi CIAndrew! Thank you very much for the corrected code! It works now!! I thought Worksheet("Sheet1") is the way to activate sheet1, so why don't I need to qualify in the second row? Thank you : )

Comment: Pasting doesn't require activation, selection is enough:
See also [Selecting vs activate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7185748/5785085) and [VBA paste range](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18969066/5785085)