# Change the Label's size and color in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to change the color of the right label—created in Excel—to blue, with the same size as the data in C5.

I'm not sure how to do it in Excel. I tried to find a solution but failed.

[image]

Comment: Is this useful to you?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8617162/fast-way-to-copy-formatting-in-excel

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure you are using an ActiveX Control label and not a Form Control Label.

Then, right click your label and select properties. In the properties list, click the font property and it will reveal an ellipsis button (...) to the right. Click the ellipsis button and select you desired size.

To change the color, select your desired color in the Forecolor property below font. (options are limited for labels).

To change via VBA, you can lookup you desired color code by selecting the color in the forecolor property mentioned above. Then, do something like this in your code:

```
Label1.Font.Size = 36
Label1.ForeColor = &H80000001
```