# Create a range using named cells

Tags: vba, excel, named-scope

I need to create a range using named cells in vba.

So far I have the following which is not working;

```
Dim pasteRange As Range
Set pasteRange = Range(firstRow, 11)

pasteRange.Value(11) = slabTemplateSheet.Range("slabTemp").Value(11)
```

Where firstRow is an Integer. slabTemplateSheet refers to a worksheet and slabTemp is a named range in said sheet.

I thought it would be fairly simple as my paste range is only 1 row and 11 columns (i.e 11 cells in a row) but I can't get it to work.

In your answer, presuming there is one, could you also please give me the ability to paste multiple rows and columns, so for instance if slabTemp refers to A1:F16

**Edit**: I didn't make it clear what I am trying to do.

I have a named range called slabTemp in the worksheet slabTemplateSheet. In another sheet I want to copy that range, including the formatting, and paste it. I heard that using the copy/paste function was slow so I found the property above that supposedly does the same thing but is faster (i haven't tested it). Source, Durgesh's answer here: [fast way to copy formatting in excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8617162/fast-way-to-copy-formatting-in-excel)

In the new sheet I need to paste it into a range which is to be created (this is what i don't know how to do)

So Range(firstRow, 11) refers to the integer saved as firstRow (a row number) and 11 is the column number. But this doesn't work.

I guess my question, is how do i create a range using names rather than say Range("A1:G6") so instead Range(firstRow1:secondRow:6)

Thanks Again!

Comment: What is the [Range.Value](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195193.aspx)(11) property? Are you confusing the **xlRangeValueXMLSpreadsheet** [XlRangeValueDataType enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837565.aspx) with eleven columns?

Comment: @Jeeped I am trying to set the value of one range to the value of a new range, i found that property here in Duresh's answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8617162/fast-way-to-copy-formatting-in-excel

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working example.

```
Public Sub CopyRange()
    'Define the Copy Range
    Dim CopyRange As Range: Set CopyRange = Range("MyCustomRange")
    'Define the range to Paste Value to
    Dim PasteRange As Range: Set PasteRange = Range("MyOtherCustomRange")
    'Move the Copy Range into the Paste Range
    'You don't need to specify the sheet name, the Defined named holds that information
    'Important: The ranges should be the same size, otherwise you may get an error
    PasteRange.Value() = CopyRange.Value()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

About how to create a *Named Range* (worksheet scope, not for Workbook per your code), use the code below. Not sure what are you trying to achieve in this line:

```
pasteRange.Value(11) = slabTemplateSheet.Range("slabTemp").Value(11)
```

Anyway, this is the code for the Named Range:

```
Sub UseNamedRange()

Dim slabTemplateSheet       As Worksheet
Dim pasteRange              As Range

Set slabTemplateSheet = Sheets("Sheet1")

' create the Named Range "slabTemp" (Named Range for Worksheet)
' you can manualy (or with variables) modify the Range("A1:F16")
slabTemplateSheet.Names.Add "slabTemp", Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:F16")
Set pasteRange = slabTemplateSheet.Range("slabTemp")

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem like you are trying to transfer the **xlRangeValueXMLSpreadsheet** [XlRangeValueDataType enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837565.aspx) of the cells; rather it sounds like you want 11 cells in a row.

```
with slabTemplateSheet.Range("slabTemp")
    pasteRange.Resize(1, 11) = .Cells.Resize(1, 11).Value
end with
```