# Copy and paste formatting is slow using VBA. How can I speed it up?

Tags: vba, performance, excel

The following code is a function that works. It's just slow and I don't know how to speed it up. It takes an excel row number and the value of it's headerval (string) and finds the same headerval on a different sheet then copies the formatting and applies it to our new sheet. The true false is because the source sheet has 2 different formatting options. It passes in the row to use either 23 or 24. ZROW is a public variable which is set with the ROW to start looking. srccolbyname function gets a col number from the source sheet which has the same headerval

```
Function formatrow(roww As Long, header As Boolean)

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim headerval As String
Dim sht As Worksheet
Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DEALSHEET")
Dim sht2 As Worksheet
Set sht2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
If header = True Then: srcrow = 23: Else: srcrow = 24
LastColumn = sht.Cells(ZROW + 1, sht.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

For x = 2 To LastColumn
headerval = sht.Cells(ZROW + 1, x).Value
srccol = srccolbyname(headerval)
sht2.Cells(srcrow, srccol).Copy 'THIS IS SLOW
sht.Cells(roww, x).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats,    Operation:=xlNone, _
    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Next x

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.ScreenUpdating = False


End Function
```

As requested here is the support function referenced above.

```
Public Function srccolbyname(strng_name As String) As Integer
Call findcol 'find ZROW
Dim x As Integer
Dim sht As Worksheet
Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
LastColumn = sht.Cells(22, sht.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    For x = 2 To LastColumn
        chkval = sht.Cells(22, x).Value
            If Trim(UCase(chkval)) = Trim(UCase(strng_name)) Then
            srccolbyname = x
            Exit For
        Else
        srccolbyname = 2
        End If
    Next x
End Function
```

Comment: For working code improvements you will get better response on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: thanks brian I didn't know about Code Review

Comment: it's a function

Comment: Can you edit the post to include the code for the `srccolbyname` function?

Comment: I added the other function.

Comment: I suspect that's where your performance hit is coming from.  How many columns are you dealing with and how many copy operations does a typical run perform?

Comment: 343 col's per call. normally only called 4 to 5 times. It seems the performance is due to copy paste between sheets. I can comment that out and code runs instantly but I need the formatting to copy I just don't know how to do it in a faster way

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are numerous ways to make your code faster, but you'll find that the copy and paste special in particular is notoriously slow. Provided that the formatting you need to preserve is simply the cell value, background color and font color, you could try to replace

```
  sht2.Cells(srcrow, srccol).Copy 
  sht.Cells(roww, x).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats,    Operation:=xlNone, _
 SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
 Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

With this:

```
 sht2.Cells(srcrow,srcol).Value=sht.Cells(roww,x).Value
 sht2.Cells(srcrow,srcol).Interior.ColorIndex=sht.Cells(roww,x).Interior.ColorIndex
 sht2.Cells(srcrow,srcol).Font.ColorIndex=sht.Cells(roww,x).Font.ColorIndex
```

You'll find that people have looked into this issue on Stack Overflow before: [fast way to copy formatting in excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8617162/fast-way-to-copy-formatting-in-excel)

If your performance issues persist, I would look into replacing your user-defined function `srccolbyname` by the `range.find` method (see more about it here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746.aspx). It seems to me to be performing the same role as this inbuilt method. Typically, these inbuilt methods will run faster than a UDF.

In general, if possible it's better to refer to a range (i.e. a collection of cells) rather than cells individually. By copy-pasting a range rather than the cells one by one, you minimize the traffic (i.e. switching back and forth) between Excel and VBA which typically hampers performance.